# Why are the number of pivot variables equal in A and the transpose of A?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

This was a fact used to prove the column rank of A was equal to the row rank of A in my textbook.

But why is this true?

Comment: [Here's](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/3004418139737.pdf.bannered.pdf) a pretty elegant proof that row rank = column rank by William Wardlaw.  Then the fact that the number of pivots variables in $A$ = number in $A^T$ follows.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a proof based on analysis of the elimination algorithm.

It does not use any higher level concepts. All that is needed to know is that the rank of a matrix equals to the number of pivots.

### A proof by understanding the algorithm of elimination

The idea is to look at the elimination algorithm and to show that the number of pivots for a matrix and it's transpose is identical.

After reading try answering the questions:

- If during elimination the $row_i$ becomes zero what does it say about it's relation with rows prior e.g. $row_j \mid 1\le j<i$? Why?
- If during elimination the next pivot element at $column_j$ becomes zero what does it say about it's relation with columns prior e.g. $column_k \mid 1 \le k < j$? Why?

#### A 2 by 2 example

This is to build intuition.

Take the matrix $M$ that yields 1 pivot $M=\begin{bmatrix}1&2\\4&8\end{bmatrix}$. After elimination the 2nd row becomes zero.

Notice then that the ratios $\frac 4 1= \frac 8 2$ are equal. Divide both sides by $4$ and multiply by $2$ to see that $\frac 2 1 = \frac 8 4$ are also equal.

This means that the 2nd column is the scaled version of the 1st column. If elimination run on $M^T=\begin{bmatrix}1&4\\2&8\end{bmatrix}$ it would similarly yield 1 pivot.

In general this is true for any 2 by 2 matrix when $row_2=c\times row_1$ for some constant $c$.

#### A 4 by 4 example

Take $M=\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1&1\\1&2&2&2\\1&3&3&3\\1&2&3&4\end{bmatrix}$ that produces 3 pivots.

Let's do some elimination

$\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1&1\\1&2&2&2\\1&3&3&3\\1&2&3&4\end{bmatrix} \rightarrow \begin{bmatrix}1&1&1&1\\0&1&1&1\\0&2&2&2\\0&1&2&3\end{bmatrix} \rightarrow \begin{bmatrix}1&1&1&1\\0&1&1&1\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&1&2\end{bmatrix}$

Why did the 3rd row become zero? In 2 by 2 example earlier the 2nd row was scaled version of the 1st. Here the 3rd row is twice the 2nd row minus the 1st row.

We can see it in elimination. First we subtracted the 1st row then we subtracted two times "the 2nd row minus the 1st row".

In total: $row_3 - row_1 - 2\times(row_2 - row_1) = row_3 - 2\times row_2 + row_1=0$. Then $row_3 = 2 \times row_2 - row_1$

This is the key. **The row becomes zero only if it is some combination of previous rows**. In linear algebra the 3rd row is also called **the duplicate row**. By loosing the row we also loose the pivot that should have been on that row. Hence **the number of duplicate rows equal the number of lost pivots**.

Let's look at the elimination of $M^T$.

$\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1&1\\1&2&3&2\\1&2&3&3\\1&2&3&4\end{bmatrix} \rightarrow \begin{bmatrix}1&1&1&1\\0&1&2&1\\0&1&2&2\\0&1&2&3\end{bmatrix} \rightarrow \begin{bmatrix}1&1&1&1\\0&1&2&1\\0&0&0&1\\0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$

Here the 3rd pivot and cells below became zero. Because in this $M^T$ $col_3=2\times col_2 - col_1$. The relations between rows of $M$ become relations between columns of $M^T$. **The pivot and cells below on the same column become zero when that column is some combination of previous columns**.

#### Conclusion

Duplicate rows and duplicate columns have no change of producing pivots. What is a duplicate row in $M$ is a duplicate column in $M^T$ and vice versa. **The number of pivots in both is the same.** Therefore the rank of the rowspace equals the rank of the column space.

This is true for any square matrix.

Answer (score -1):

The number of pivots of $A$ is its column rank, say $k$. The
column rank of $A$ is equal to the row rank of A, which is the column rank of $A^T$.

Hence, $A^T$ must have the same number of pivots as $A$.

Comment: "This was a fact used to [prove] that the column rank of A was equal to the row rank of A" Your answer looks to me like circular argumentation.

Comment: Precisely my point, and the reason why I m confused.